# Recognition and conversion of characters in specific positions

Tags: python, pandas, find, range

**Input:**

```
0      1     2
TNN    R11W  MSLQEMFRFPRGLLLGSVLLVASAPATL
ASTN1  E5V   MALAALCALLACCWGPAAVLATAAGDVDPSK
HSPB7  H19P  MSHRTSSTFRAERSFHSSHSSSSSSTSSSASRALPAQDPPMEK
CLCNKB C3Y   MECFVGLREGSSGNPVTLQELWGPCPRIRRGIRG
SZRD1  P10L  MEDEEVAESWEEAADSGEIDRRLEKKL
```

**Expected output:**

```
0      1     2
TNN    R11W  MSLQEMFRFPWGLLLGSVLLVASAPATL
ASTN1  E5V   NaN
HSPB7  H19P  MSHRTSSTFRAERSFHSSPSSSSSSTSSSASRALPAQDPPMEK
CLCNKB C3Y   MEYFVGLREGSSGNPVTLQELWGPCPRIRRGIRG
SZRD1  P10L  NaN
```

**Code: examples**

```
with open('temp.txt', 'w') as fw:
    for x in range(len(merge_two_files[1])):
        for i in range(len(merge_two_files[2])):
            if merge_two_files[1][x] == something:
                data = anything
                fw.write(str(data))
```

I wanna change a character in 'column 2' with the index of 'column 1'. For example, in first row, if I check the index of 'column 1', I will fine 'R' in 11th character of 'column 2'. If the character is 'R', I wanna change it as 'W'. If not, I wanna write 'NaN' in the cell. I'm sorry but is there any suggestion for me with Pandas?

Comment: What you have labelled "output" - is that your *actual* output, or your *desired* output? What happens when you run your code, and why is that wrong? Also, how are we supposed to interpret that code? We don't have a value for `something` or for `anything`.

Comment: Please read [ask] and explain your thinking about the problem. What do you think are the logical steps required to solve the problem? For example, If I gave you code that could handle one row, would you be able to use that to process the entire datatable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write a custom function:

```
def replace_char(row):
    # explode 'R11W' into c='R', p=11, r='W'
    c, p, r =  (row[1][0], int(row[1][1:-1]), row[1][-1])
    s1 = row[2]
    s2 = np.NaN
    if s1[p-1] == c:
        s2 = f"{s1[:p-1]}{r}{s1[p:]}"
    return s2

df[2] = df.apply(replace_char, axis=1)
```

Output:

```
>>> df
        0     1                                            2
0     TNN  R11W                 MSLQEMFRFPWGLLLGSVLLVASAPATL
1   ASTN1   E5V                                          NaN
2   HSPB7  H19P  MSHRTSSTFRAERSFHSSPSSSSSSTSSSASRALPAQDPPMEK
3  CLCNKB   C3Y           MEYFVGLREGSSGNPVTLQELWGPCPRIRRGIRG
4   SZRD1  P10L                                          NaN
```

Setup:

```
df = pd.read_csv('file1', header=None)
print(df)

# Output:
        0     1                                            2
0   ASTN1   E5V              MALAALCALLACCWGPAAVLATAAGDVDPSK
1   HSPB7  H19P  MSHRTSSTFRAERSFHSSHSSSSSSTSSSASRALPAQDPPMEK
2  CLCNKB   C3Y           MECFVGLREGSSGNPVTLQELWGPCPRIRRGIRG
3   SZRD1  P10L                  MEDEEVAESWEEAADSGEIDRRLEKKL
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately, the terminal says 'IndexError: string index out of range'. Idk why but I read this file with Pandas. I think it's the problem.

Comment: Maybe if you share your file, it will be easier to debug (dropbox, wetransfer, google drive, ...)

Comment: I really appreciate you. Then, could you let me  your 'google drive' account?

Comment: Share your file for everyone if someone has a better answer than me.

Comment: You didn't share your file so it's difficult to fix my code.

Comment: I'm so sorry but I can't share my file cuz I work for a company, and the file is proprietary to my company. If I share the file with you, I might lose my job. Plz understand me.

Answer (score 0):

This is my answer :

```
data = [["TNN",    "R11W",  "MSLQEMFRFPRGLLLGSVLLVASAPATL"], ["ASTN1",  "E5V",   "MALAALCALLACCWGPAAVLATAAGDVDPSK"],
["HSPB7",  "H19P",  "MSHRTSSTFRAERSFHSSHSSSSSSTSSSASRALPAQDPPMEK"],
["CLCNKB", "C3Y",   "MECFVGLREGSSGNPVTLQELWGPCPRIRRGIRG"],
["SZRD1",  "P10L",  "MEDEEVAESWEEAADSGEIDRRLEKKL"]]


result = []

for row in data:
    res_row = []
    res_row.append(row[0])
    res_row.append(row[1])

    c1 = row[1][0]
    c2 = row[1][-1]
    num = int(row[1][1:-1])


    if row[2][num-1] == c1:
        c3 = (row[2])
        l = list(c3)
        l[num-1] = c2
        c3=''.join(l)
        res_row.append(c3)
    else:
        res_row.append("NaN")

    result.append(res_row)

print(result)
```

Comment: I suppose if the OP tagged his post with `pandas`, it's probably because the input is a dataframe.

Comment: @Corralien you are probably right, but I he did not specify it himself in his example so I did what was easiest for me

Comment: @Vaggelis_Lazarakis I'm sorry I was wrong. I wanted to get an idea with Pandas, but your answer is nice. Thank you very much.